Help with completing a derivation of usefulness of cross-validation
This question is raised as a result of my attempt to answer this other question of mine.
Let's refer to all our prior knowledge, both explicit and implicit, as $X_\text{true}$. Almost always, we are unable to fully formalize $X_\text{true}$. So we end up using a different formalizable prior knowledge in our Bayesian computations that estimates this true prior, which I call $X_\text{est}$. Now, let's say we have two different models $A$ and $B$, and each of them fully describes a likelihood function for our observed data $D_\text{o}$ so that $P(D|A,X_\text{true})=P(D|A,X_\text{est})$ and the same for $B$ for any dataset $D$. We are interested in deciding whether $A$ or $B$ is more plausible. It follows from Cox's theorem that if $P(A|D_\text{o},X_\text{true}) > P(B|D_\text{o},X_\text{true})$, then $A$ is more plausible, and vice versa. Since we cannot formalize $X_\text{true}$, we might be tempted to use $X_\text{est}$ instead. But this can result in choosing the model that, while assigns a higher likelihood to $D_\text{o}$, is actually less plausible according to $X_\text{true}$ (This, BTW, is what I think of when I encounter the term "overfitting").
Now, I thought maybe the reason cross-validation (as an estimation of expected log predictive density (ELPD)) is useful is that it can help us solve this problem. For instance, maybe we can show that
$$
P(A|D_\text{o},X_\text{true}) > P(B|D_\text{o},X_\text{true}) \iff \text{ELPD}(A) > \text{ELPD}(B)
$$
where
$$
\begin{align}
\text{ELPD}(A)&=\mathop{\mathbb{E}}_{D_\text{new}\sim P(.|D_\text{o}, X_\text{true})}\log P(D_\text{new}|A,D_\text{o},X_\text{est})\\&=\mathop{\mathbb{E}}_{D_\text{new}\sim P(.|D_\text{o}, X_\text{true})}\log P(D_\text{new}|A,D_\text{o},X_\text{true})
\end{align}
$$
And the same for $B$.
We can also write:
$$
P(A|D_\text{o},X_\text{true})=\mathop{\mathbb{E}}_{D_\text{new}\sim P(.|D_\text{o}, X_\text{true})}P(A|D_\text{new}, D_\text{o},X_\text{true})
$$
But further manipulating these formulas doed not lead me anywhere.
Does what I say here make any sense? Can you help me complete this derivation of usefulness of ELPD and cross-validation?
